# A die is rolled $6$ times, a number greater than $4$ occurs at most $5$ times?

Tags: probability, random-variables, binomial-coefficients, random

> What is the probability that, when a $6$-sided die is rolled $6$ times, a number greater than $4$ occurs at most
> $5$ times?

Let $X$ be a random variable that equals $1$ when you roll a $5$ or $6$, and a $0$ when you pick $1$ through $4$. More explicitly speaking:

$$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^6 X_i \leq 5\right)=1-P\left( \sum_{i=1}^6 X_i > 5\right)$$

The specific cases where $\{\sum_{i=1}^6 X_i >5\}$ is when you have all fives or all sixes.

The probability of picking a $5$ six times is $(1/6^6) \cdot {6 \choose 6}$ which equals the probability of picking a six, six times.

I think $$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^6 X_i \leq 5\right)=1-P\left( \sum_{i=1}^6 X_i > 5\right)=1-\frac{2}{6^6}$$

Is this right?

---

Edit:

I think

$$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^6 X_i \leq 5\right)=1-P\left( \sum_{i=1}^6 X_i > 5\right)= 1- \sum_{j=0}^6 {6 \choose j}(\dfrac{1}{6^6})$$

Comment: *"The specific cases where $\{\sum_{i=1}^6 X_i >5\}$ is when you have all fives or all sixes."* --
No, it is when you have "5 or 6" on each of the six rolls.

Comment: Consider $$1 - \left[\frac{2}{6}\right]^6.$$

Comment: @user1108315 Note that your edit leads to  
$\sum_{j=0}^6 {6 \choose j}({1\over 6})^6=({1\over 6})^6\sum_{j=0}^6 {6 \choose j}=({1\over 6})^6 2^6=({2\over 6})^6$, because by the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement) $\sum_{j=0}^6 {6 \choose j}=2^6.$

Comment: There are a lot of probability questions where the negation of the event has a much easier probability to calculate. Recall that $P(E) + P(\lnot E) = 1$.